# fopen - raw data as stream data in C

Tags: c, fopen

I need to create a FILE struct from data stored into an array. 
In my code I have the fopen function, which returns a FILE. The idea is to read all data stored in array, convert to FILE struct and finally return the FILE.

I.e:

```
FILE validFile (char *fileName){
     char *data;
     FILE *fp;

     data = malloc(sizeof(char*));

     populateData(data);

     fp = fopen(data, "r");

     return fp;
}
```

Is that possible?

Thanks and best regards,
Cristian.

Comment: What operating system are you working on? POSIX provides a solution for this, although I'm not sure about Windows.

Comment: fp is a FILE*, not a FILE

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is possible, although not with pure C. If you program for a Unix-like operating system like Linux, you can use the [`fmemopen`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fmemopen.html) function from POSIX:

```
FILE validFile (char *fileName){
     char *data;
     FILE *fp;

     data = populateData();

     /* data_size is the length of the buffer */
     fp = fmemopen(data, data_size, "r");

     return fp;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Another problem I see with the code you've posted is that `fp` is a stack aka automatic variable; once your `validFile()` function returns, `fp` goes out of scope and it's value is undefined.

You can return `fp` if you change its storage class, it's scope, pass it as a parameter, allocate it with `malloc()`, `calloc()`... Something like this, for instance:

```
FILE **validFile (char *fileName){
     char *data;
     FILE **fpp;

     if (fpp = (FILE **)calloc(1,sizeof(FILE *))) {

        data = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char*));

        populateData(data);

        if ((*fpp = fmemopen(data, data_size, "r"))) {

           /*
            */

        } else {

           /*
            */

        }

     } else {
        /*
         * calloc() failed...
         */
     }

     return *fpp;
}
```

Comment: Hi Larry. Thanks for your help. I'm programming in Standard C, I have not access to fmemopen. Is it possible to provide me the fmemopen function implementation in order to move it to my project? Where I can find the source code? Thanks and best regards. Cristian.

Comment: Your first paragraph is just wrong -- yes `fp` is a local variable, but it is returned by value, not reference, so there are no dangling references here.  Allocating extra memory to hold it just leaks memory and doesn't achieve anything positive.

Comment: @cristiancrm What operating system are you programming for? This question is crucial.

Comment: @ChrisDodd Thanks for spotting and pointing out my error. You're completely correct; there aren't any dangling references. I fixed what I thought I saw, not what was actually right in front of me. Hopefully, I didn't cause too much confusion in the process.

Comment: Hi all. In my case I'm developing embeded system for TI microcontrollers based on C. Regards.

Comment: @cristiancrm Which toolchain are you using? The msp430gcc toolchain provides `fmemopen` I believe, but on the other hand, why do you want to use stdio on a microcontroller anyway?